# Modifying the tablefilter jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tablefilter

I need to modify [this plug-in](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tablefilter.shtml) to support not(!), (!=), (AND), (OR) operators and add some range filtering. I tried to add an `elseif` statement on line 412 but it doesn't work. Here is the code that I've added.

```
else if(/!/.test(SearchArgs[j]) && !isNaN(num_cell_data))
{
    num_cell_data != parseFloat(SearchArgs[j].replace(/!/,"")) ?
    occurence[j] = true :
    occurence[j] = false;
}
```

Comment: i got it working now...i don't know why the !not operator does not work...maybe there is a bug somewhere in my code...anayways i've manage to make the functionality to work the way i want...thank you so much for your help... :)

Comment: @Ryan, Put your answer and mark it.

Comment: Great, i don't know the problem and now I don't know the answer. How did this get voted up so much?

Answer (score 1):

num_cell_data could be integer or string, try add parseFloat to num_cell_data:

```
parseFloat(num_cell_data) != parseFloat(SearchArgs[j].replace(/!/,"")) ? ...
```